# form radio redirect on submit

Tags: javascript

I want to make a small quiz for web site.
when each radio from question (1) and question (2) is checked it should redirect.

```
<form action="" method="post">

<p>Question (1)</p>
    <span>500</span>
        <input type="radio" value="a1"/>
        <span>1000</span>
        <input type="radio" value="b2"/>
        <span>2000</span>
        <input type="radio" value="c3"/>

<p>Question (2)</p>
    <span>1000</span>
        <input type="radio" value="a4"/>
        <span>2000</span>
        <input type="radio" value="b5"/>

<input type="button" value="Go" />

</form>

a1 + a4 redirect to a.html
a1 + b5 redirect to b.html
b2 + a4 redirect to c.html
b2 + b5 redirect to d.html
c3 + a4 redirect to e.html
c3 + b5 redirect to f.html
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What the actual problem is ?? why do u need so many pages to navigate over ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use javascript for this purpose check radio before submitting and submit page using javascript